# "Unexpected character '" when importing theme

Tags: css, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying import the element ui chalk theme with

```
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css'
```

But I get this in the console:

> Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '

Am I missing something?

Comment: Check the stack trace, if you can share screenshot shot of whole error or log it would be easier. This error is mostly you added additional character by mistake or improper code

Comment: Are you using a linter? Perhaps your linter is set to only accept double quotes and not single quotes. Try changing to double quotes, perhaps that will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following [this guide](https://medium.com/@mahesh.ks/using-sass-scss-in-vue-js-2-d472af0facf9) I managed to fix this

Basically had to install `sass-loader` with

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass style-loader --save-dev
```

and then add the loader to my `webpack.config.js`, but I had to do it like this, due to my version:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        { test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/, loader: 'style!css!sass' },
    ]
}
```